# Operations in nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

New to Mathematica, I have a nested list containing many lists(A) of 16 lists(B) of 3 integers(C).
I wish to put in each (Aj, Bi, C2) the result of (Aj, Bi-1, C2)+(Aj, Bi, C1).
I could do it with a loop, or a spreadsheet, but is there a more elegant way to do this using functions like Accumulate?
I simplified the data here:

```
 myList = 
    {{{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
    {{g, h}, {i, j}, {k, l}}, 
    {{m, n}, {o, p}, {q, r}}, 
    {{s, t}, {u, v}, {w, x}}}
```

A simple replacement test function before using values of other elements:

```
myF[x_] := x*2
ReplacePart[myList, {_, _, 2} -> xx]
```

Result:

```
{{{a, xx}, {c, xx}, {e, xx}}, 
{{g, xx}, {i, xx}, {k, xx}}, 
{{m, xx}, {o, xx}, {q, xx}},
{{s, xx}, {u, xx}, {w, xx}}}
```

I tried many expressions in the function without success.

```
ReplacePart[myList, {_, _, 2} -> myF[ ??? ]]
```

should result:

```
{{{a, 2b}, {c, 2d}, {e, 2f}}, 
{{g, 2h}, {i, 2j}, {k, 2l}}, 
{{m, 2n}, {o, 2p}, {q, 2r}}, 
{{s, 2t}, {u, 2v}, {w, 2x}}}
```

How could Accumulate give this?

```
{{{a, a}, {c, a+c}, {e, a+c+e}}, 
{{g, g}, {i, g+i}, {k, g+i+k}}, 
{{m, m}, {o, m+o}, {q, m+o+q}}, 
{{s, s}, {u, s+u}, {w, s+u+w}}}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The solutions are so concise and powerful!  It's very exiting to discover in the same time Mathematica and Stackexchange.
Thank you march, ubpdqn and eldo for your answers.

Comment: For the first one, after [Mr Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115088/106): `myList.{{1, 0}, {0, 2}}`. Very fast, I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
myList = {
  {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}}, 
  {{g, h}, {i, j}, {k, l}}, 
  {{m, n}, {o, p}, {q, r}}, 
  {{s, t}, {u, v}, {w, x}}
 };
```

For the first, one could do

```
MapAt[2 # &, myList, {All, All, 2}]
(* {
  {{a, 2*b}, {c, 2*d}, {e, 2*f}}, 
  {{g, 2*h}, {i, 2*j}, {k, 2*l}}, 
  {{m, 2*n}, {o, 2*p}, {q, 2*r}}, 
  {{s, 2*t}, {u, 2*v}, {w, 2*x}}
 } *)
```

or with your

```
myF[x_] := x*2
```

do

```
MapAt[myF, myList, {All, All, 2}]
```

---

As for the second, here's another version that is basically equivalent to `ubpdqn`'s, but slightly less verbose:

```
Thread@{#, Accumulate@#} &@#[[All, 1]] & /@ myList
```

Or, a trickier variant:

```
Thread@{#, Accumulate@#} & @@@ Thread /@ myList
```

Here's a version that uses `ReplaceAll`, with a dummy variable to update so that we don't have to `Accumulate`:

```
Map[
  Module[{var = 0}, # /. {a_, b_} :> (var = var + a; {a, var})] &
  , myList
 ]
```

However, `ReplaceAll` with this pattern will fail when the sub-list is two elements long. Instead, we use `Replace`, and make the code more concise:

```
Module[{var = 0}, 
  Replace[#, {a_, b_} :> {a, var = var + a}, 2]
 ] & /@ myList
```

Comment: Completely new to me that one can combine `MapAt` with `All`. Very handy, +1

Answer (score 6):

I believe this achieves your goal:

```
Join @@ Map[Transpose[{#, Accumulate@#}] &, Transpose /@ myList, {2}]
```

`Transpose` is a very helpful function. This also exploits the level argument for `Map` and `Join` just recombines.

There are many ways to do things in Mathematica. There will no doubt other approaches.

Comment: This will be faster on packed arrays: `Transpose[{#, Accumulate@#} &@First@Transpose[myList, {3, 2, 1}], {3, 2, 1}]`.

Answer (score 5):

`ReplacePart` is not the natural choice to apply a function to the innermost matrix elements. Simple and straightforward is `ReplaceAll`:

```
myList /. {a_, b_} :> {a, myF @ b} // MatrixForm
```

[image]

With very large matrices `ReplaceAll` can get slow. In this case one can do an "inline" replacement. Since this permanently changes `myList` we do it with a copy:

```
copy = myList;

copy[[All, All, 2]] *= 2;
```

Thanks @MichaelE2 for this terse notation

```
copy
```

[image]

Accumulate with

```
Transpose /@ Transpose[{#, Accumulate /@ #}] &[myList[[All, All, 1]]] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: I think `copy[[All, All, 2]] *= 2` will be faster on longer, large packed arrays. (+1)

Comment: Of course, thanks for this valuable advice - will update :)