# Flip sign of one variable in list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list of x, y-pairs `l={{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}`.
Now I need to flip the sign of the y values only before plotting.
What is the easiest way to do this modification?

Comment: `{1, -1} # & /@ l` or `Transpose@{#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &@Transpose[l]`

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Or even faster `Transpose[{1, -1} # &@Transpose[l]]`

Comment: Or `MapAt[-# &, l, {All, 2}]`. Or `{#1, -#2} & @@@ l`.

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate. I will see if I can find it.

Comment: `l /. {a_, b_} :> {a, -b}`

Comment: one more.. ` l ConstantArray[{1, -1}, Length@l] `

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(38138)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38138/121) @march

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html) works well here.

```
pts = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}};

pts.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}
```

> ```
> {{x1, -y1}, {x2, -y2}, {x3, -y3}, {x4, -y4}}
> ```

In version 10.1.0 under Windows x64 this is twice as fast as BlacKow's fastest method:

```
l = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000000, 2}];

Transpose[{1, -1} Transpose[l]]   // RepeatedTiming // First

l.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}}               // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.0133
>
> 0.0072
> ```

Comment: I was so sure that you can't do this, that it will cause some dimensions mismatch, so I haven't even tried this... I'll add it to my benchmark later. Thanks!

Comment: I like this. Nice to see you using dot products! :)

Comment: @J.M. There is a pretty good chance you taught me this but my memory is too poor to remember.

Comment: @J.M. Do you feel that this is a duplicate of [(38138)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38138/121)?  I do, but not strongly, and I did not wish to act alone.

Comment: Somehow I recall another thread with the exact same problem of reflecting, but the link escapes me at the moment. BTW, I'm sure you know this, but for general scaling and reflection, one could use `DiagonalMatrix[]`, or even `ScalingTransform[]`.

Answer (score 12):

Little benchmark to compare suggested methods:

```
l = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {1000000, 2}];
b1[l_List] := {1, -1} # & /@ l;
b2[l_List] := Transpose@{#[[1]], -#[[2]]} &@Transpose[l];
b3[l_List] := Transpose[{1, -1} Transpose[l]];
m1[l_List] := MapAt[-# &, l, {All, 2}];
m2[l_List] := {#1, -#2} & @@@ l;
ch1[l_List] := l /. {a_, b_} :> {a, -b};
g1[l_List] := l ConstantArray[{1, -1}, Length@l];
w1[l_List] := l.{{1, 0}, {0, -1}};
fb1[l_List] := Thread[{l[[;; , 1]], -l[[;; , 2]]}];

#2 -> #1 & @@@ SortBy[#, #[[1]] &] &@({#1, #2} & @@@Transpose@{First@AbsoluteTiming[#[l]] & /@ #, #}&@{b1, b2, b3,m1, m2, ch1, g1,w1,fb1})
```

> `{w1 -> 0.007054, b3 -> 0.016369, b2 -> 0.020753, b1 -> 0.155566, 
>    fb1 -> 0.25016, g1 -> 0.323931, m2 -> 1.05527, m1 -> 1.13127, 
>    ch1 -> 1.32451}`

Comment: b3 is the last thing I would have used without much thinking, neat to see how much faster it is though.

Comment: @FrankBreitling Usually you create a new list in Mathematica and not modify existing one. Your method `l=Thread[{l[[1]], -l[[2]]}]` doesn't yield desired result.

Comment: you could write `b3` as `Transpose[{1, -1} Transpose@l]` (+1)

Comment: @kglr Indeed... not sure why I came up with that one lol.. Fixed

Comment: ... not only it is the fastest but also the shortest if you write it as `({1,-1} l)`:)

Comment: @kglr I can't see superscript T in Safari on Mac.

Comment: @BlacKow, it shows as a box in Chrome on Windows too. But if you copy/paste into mma it renders properly: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JtBg3.png)

Comment: Thank you, that's very interesting! How does this compare to `l=Thread[{l[[;;,1]], -l[[;;,2]]}]` I had thought about? Are these methods creating new lists or just modifying the existing list which is interesting with respect to memory usage?

Comment: @FrankBreitling I updated my answer with your method.

Comment: @BlacKow Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
list * Threaded[{1, -1}]
```

{{x1, -y1}, {x2, -y2}, {x3, -y3}, {x4, -y4}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `Cases` and `PauliMatrix[3]`:

```
pts = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}};

Cases[pts, v_ :> v . PauliMatrix[3]]

(*{{x1, -y1}, {x2, -y2}, {x3, -y3}, {x4, -y4}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am glad to see that people are using `Threaded`

I am surprised nobody mentioned the use of [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html)

Grabbing the list from @eldo

```
list = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}};
```

This

```
Inner[Times, list, {1, -1}, List]
```

returns

> `{{x1, -y1}, {x2, -y2}, {x3, -y3}, {x4, -y4}}`

We can, also, use [`Splice`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html)

```
Cases[list, x_ :> {First@x, Splice@Rest@-x}]
```

> `{{x1, -y1}, {x2, -y2}, {x3, -y3}, {x4, -y4}}`

And [`ApplyTo`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplyTo.html)

```
list = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}};
list //= ReplaceAt[x_ :> -x, {All, 2}];
list
```

giving

> `{{x1, -y1}, {x2, -y2}, {x3, -y3}, {x4, -y4}}`

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}, {x4, y4}};

SubsetMap[-# &, list, {All, 2}]
SequenceCases[list, {{a_, b_}} :> {a, -b}]
list . ReflectionMatrix[{0, 1}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{x1, -y1}, {x2, -y2}, {x3, -y3}, {x4, -y4}}