# Apply function to a specific column

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have some data:

```
data={{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3},{a4,b4},...}
```

and I would like to apply the function:

`f1[x_]=x*5` to every `a_i` element.

How can I do this?

The best solution I've found so far is to do:

```
MapAt[f1, data, {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}...}]
```

Up to the length of my data, but I'm sure there's a more efficient solution for this.

Comment: `MapAt[f1, data, {All, 1}]`?

Comment: `Map[Apply[{f[#1], ##2} &], data]`, if you insist... but J.M.'s approach is best.

Comment: `Transpose@{f1[#1], #2} & @@ Transpose@data` If your `f1` is `Listable` (and yours is ) that can give you significant speed increase.

Comment: And [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115058/flip-sign-of-one-variable-in-list/115062#115062) you can find different methods to do similar things

Comment: J.M. answer does indeed work perfectly. Thank you guys!

Comment: also: `{f1@#, #2} & @@@ data`

Comment: @kglr probably `{f1@#1, #2} & @@@ data`

Comment: @BlacKow `#1` and `#` are equivalent.

Comment: For the case in question, and after [Mr Wizard's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115088/106), `data.{{5, 0}, {0, 1}}`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Just seems clearer to me to use `#1` when you got more than one argument

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of ways (if I understand aim),e.g.:

```
lst = data = {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}, {a4, b4}};
lst /. {x_, y_} :> {f[x], y}
MapAt[f, lst, {All, 1}]
{f@#1, #2} & @@@ lst
```

Comment: Whenever I do one of these solutions I get the resulting list
$
{{a1,{b1}},{a2,{b2}},etc.}}$.
How do I remove the resulting list around the second element?

Comment: @ElyEastman what input are you using. The code applies function to first part of each element

Comment: I realized I was using an incorrect input for my function. It was dividing by a list element, which would encapsulate bi in a list.