# Subtracting elements in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, pure-function

I have a list containing 500 rows, each of 37 elements; i.e., a 500 x 37 matrix.

My goal is to substract in each row each element from the first. My approach in mind is to call each list by a PureFunction and then to subtract the second element from the first, then the third from the first so in the end I would have a list with 500 sublists, each with 36 elements. I failed to figure out how to call single elements if, as in my case, the the list is called by a PureFunction. I also tried to work with slots, again failing to call the single elements of the already called list. 
I highly appreciat any help or comments!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `mat` is your matrix, the following should be fast:

```
mat . SparseArray[
    {{1,_} -> 1, Band[{2,1}] -> -1},
    Dimensions[mat][[2]]+{0,-1}
]
```

**Addendum**

Here is a brief speed comparison of the 4 suggested methods:

```
wreach[m_] := m[[All, 1]] - m[[All, 2 ;;]]
carl[m_] := m . SparseArray[
    {{1, _} -> 1, Band[{2, 1}] -> -1}, 
    Dimensions[m][[2]] + {0, -1}
]
goldberg[m_] := #1 - {##2} & @@@ m
tom[m_] := #[[1]] - #[[2 ;;]] & /@ m
```

A sample matrix:

```
mat = RandomReal[10^6, {10^5, 30}];
```

Speed comparison:

```
r1 = carl[mat]; // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = wreach[mat]; // AbsoluteTiming
r3 = goldberg[mat]; // AbsoluteTiming
r4 = tom[mat]; // AbsoluteTiming
r1 === r2 === r3 === r4
```

> {0.013968, Null}
>
> {0.029711, Null}
>
> {1.4249, Null}
>
> {0.346468, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Incredible. Care to explain how your at first glance complicated solution is faster than the obvious vectorization approach of wreach? +1

Comment: @LLlAMnYP My solution constructs a `SparseArray` object (basically instantaneous) and then does 1 `Dot` product of two matrices. Matrix multiplication is probably one of the most highly optimized algorithms in the numerical analysis literature, and even more highly optimized would be matrix multiplication with a sparse array. So, I'm not surprised my solution is fast. It is a bit surprising that it is faster than a single subtraction of a matrix from a vector. Probably there is some overhead in threading the vector/matrix subtraction.

Comment: *It is a bit surprising that it is faster than a single subtraction of a matrix from a vector.* Exactly that was my question. It *is* surprising.

Answer (score 6):

If the use of a pure function is not mandatory, then given a matrix `m` we can write:

```
m[[All, 1]] - m[[All, 2;;]]
```

Here is a small example:

```
m = {{10, 1, 2, 3}, {100, 10, 20, 30}, {1000, 100, 200, 300}};

m // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

```
m[[All, 1]] - m[[All, 2;;]] // MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: Obvious approach I would go for as well. +1 now I have to think of something better...

Answer (score 4):

A 4 x 3 matrix is good enough to demonstrate a pure function that will do what you ask.

```
SeedRandom[2]; a = RandomInteger[10, {4, 3}]
```

> `{{8, 4, 5}, {4, 7, 4}, {0, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 7}}`

```
{##2} - #1 & @@@ a
```

> `{{-4, -3}, {3, 0}, {1, 0}, {-1, 3}}`

Note that `@@@` applies the pure function at level 1 of the matrix, i.e., at the level of the rows. See [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)