# add columns of list {a0,b0} to columns of list {{a0,b0} ,{a1,b1} ,{a2,b2} ...{ax,bx} }

Tags: matrix, vector, list-manipulation

If I want to add the columns of {1,2} to each of the columns of say

{{1,2},{3,2},{4,2}}

resulting in

```
{{2, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}}
```

How would I do this?  and for any given number of rows?

{{1,2},{3,2}...{x,y}}

Comment: [Add a vector to a list of vectors](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95033/2090)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time anyone says "I want to do x to every item in a list" think `Map`

```
m={{1,2},{3,2},{4,2}};
Map[#+{1,2}&,m]
```

which returns

```
{{2,4},{4,4},{5,4}}
```

If that `#` and `&` stuff is too confusing then you can do the same by writing your own function

```
m={{1,2},{3,2},{4,2}};
f[v_]:=v+{1,2};
Map[f,m]
```

which returns

```
{{2,4},{4,4},{5,4}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way.

```
pts = {{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}};
TranslationTransform[First@pts] /@ pts
```

```
pts = {{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}};
ConstantArray[{1, 0, 0}, Length@pts] . pts + pts
```

> `{{2, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}}`

Answer (score 2):

Two (of probably very many) ways:

```
data//With[{x = #[[1]]},ArrayReduce[x+#&,#,2]]&

(* {{2, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}} *)
```

or

```
data//With[{x = #[[1]]},x+#&/@#]&
```

where

```
data ={{1,2},{3,2},{4,2}}
```

**Edit**

Add a column to *all* columns (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147531/106) by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll))

```
addColToAll[mat_,col_] := With[{x=col},mat.SparseArray[{{x,x}->2,Band[{1, 1}]->1,
    {x,_}->1},Dimensions[mat][[2]]]]
```

Add a row to *all* rows:

```
addRowToAll[mat_,row_] := With[{x=row},Transpose[mat].SparseArray[{{x,x}->2,Band[{1, 1}]->1,{x,_}->1},Dimensions[mat][[1]]]//Transpose]
```

Examples

```
addRowToAll[data,1]
(* {{2, 4}, {4, 4}, {5, 4}} *)

addRowToAll[data,2]
(* {{4, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 4}} *)

addRowToAll[data,3]
(* {{5, 4}, {7, 4}, {8, 4}}

addColToAll[data,1]

(* {{2, 3}, {6, 5}, {8, 6}} *) 

data

(* {{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {4, 2}}  *)
```